# Can I associate an entitlement to all my accounts in bulk? What is the best way to implement SLA on cases?

Tags: salesforce, account, salesforce-lightning, entitlements, milestone

We use Cases as a back office in my org. Recently, our client asked that these internal processes have an SLA tied to them. That's when I tried to implement milestones.

I read the documentation and know some limitations concerning entitlement/account master detail.

I understand that for all my accounts to have an entitlement, subsequently an entitlement process with milestones, I do have to associate the entitlement with an account.

Is this the only way? To have an entitlement registry for every account I have?

What would be the best course of action here?

Is there a way to create a parent account that has all my accounts in the database as its children? Should I try to approach entitlements differently?

Any help is appreciated.

I've tried to populate the parent account field to create a case that would inherit its parent entitlements, though it did not work. The milestone field wasn't active.